# Unsupported argument for_each from terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to create a multiple delivery rules for the azure cdn endpoint through terraform.
But while trying to achieve the same getting below error,

Error: Unsupported argument

> │
> on main.tf line 71, in resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "default":
> 71:     for_each = {
> │
> An argument named "for_each" is not expected here.
> ╵

```
delivery_rule {
    for_each = {
      for deliveryrule in var.delivery_rules : deliveryrule.name => deliveryrule
    }
    name  = each.value.name
    order = each.value.order
    request_scheme_condition {
      operator     = each.value.operator
      match_values = each.value.match_values

    }
    url_redirect_action {
      redirect_type = each.value.redirect_type #"Found"
      protocol      = each.value.protocol #"Https"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [dynamic blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks):

```
dynamic "delivery_rule" {
    for_each = {
      for deliveryrule in var.delivery_rules : deliveryrule.name => deliveryrule   
   }
   
   content {
    name  = delivery_rule.value.name
    order = delivery_rule.value.order
    request_scheme_condition {
      operator     = delivery_rule.value.operator
      match_values = delivery_rule.value.match_values

    }
    url_redirect_action {
      redirect_type = delivery_rule.value.redirect_type #"Found"
      protocol      = delivery_rule.value.protocol #"Https"
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: The above one is working fine but the argument **match_values** is expecting to pass list of  values ["HTTP","HTTPS"] as of now my **var.delivery_rules** type is list(map(string)). Through list(map(string)) i'm not able to pass list of value to the  **match_values**

Comment: @hari989 Please make new question for the new issue. In the current question you even haven't provided what `var.delivery_rules` is.

Comment: Sure Marcin, Thanks for the above answer